# CSS for Scalable Puzzle over image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to accomplish something to no avail. What I need is a square div 1000x1000px) that scales down when the browser scales, maintaining it's square, and scaling it's contents down with it. The div has a background image, that should not repeat, and 4 divs with a class "puzzleRow" which each have 4 divs with the class "puzzlePiece".

Each puzzlePiece contains an svg for clicking. and a puzzle image that is meant to overflow so they can connect. Here's my html....

```
<body>
        <div id="contentContainer"></div>
        <div id="column">
            <div id="container">
                <div class="puzzleRow">
                    <div class="puzzPiece">
                        <img src="topLeft.png"></img>
                        <div class="clickArea" linkto="puzzle01.html"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="puzzPiece">
                        <img src="topA.png"></img>
                        <div class="clickArea" linkto="puzzle02.html"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="puzzPiece">
                        <img src="topB.png"></img>
                        <div class="clickArea" linkto="puzzle03.html"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="puzzPiece">
                        <img src="topRight.png"></img>
                        <div class="clickArea" linkto="puzzle04.html"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="puzzleRow">
                    <div class="puzzPiece">
                        <img src="leftA.png"></img>
                        <div class="clickArea" linkto="puzzle05.html"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="puzzPiece">
                        <img src="midA.png"></img>
                        <div class="clickArea" linkto="puzzle06.html"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="puzzPiece">
                        <img src="midB.png"></img>
                        <div class="clickArea" linkto="puzzle07.html"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="puzzPiece">
                        <img src="rightA.png"></img>
                        <div class="clickArea" linkto="puzzle08.html"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="puzzleRow">
                    <div class="puzzPiece">
                        <img src="leftB.png"></img>
                        <div class="clickArea" linkto="puzzle09.html"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="puzzPiece">
                        <img src="midB.png"></img>
                        <div class="clickArea" linkto="puzzle10.html"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="puzzPiece">
                        <img src="midA.png"></img>
                        <div class="clickArea" linkto="puzzle11.html"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="puzzPiece">
                        <img src="rightB.png"></img>
                        <div class="clickArea" linkto="puzzle12.html"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="puzzleRow">
                    <div class="puzzPiece">
                        <img src="btmLeft.png"></img>
                        <div class="clickArea" linkto="puzzle13.html"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="puzzPiece">
                        <img src="btmA.png"></img>
                        <div class="clickArea" linkto="puzzle14.html"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="puzzPiece">
                        <img src="btmB.png"></img>
                        <div class="clickArea" linkto="puzzle15.html"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="puzzPiece">
                        <img src="btmRight.png"></img>
                        <div class="clickArea" linkto="puzzle16.html"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

As far as css I have...

```
#column{
    max-width:1000px;
    max-height:1000px;
}
#container{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background-image: url('bck.png');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.puzzleRow {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


.puzzPiece {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

This is almost perfect, except that if I change the 250px height on the puzzlePieces to 25% then there will be nothing to give the thing any size and it all drops down to a teeny square with no visible content. I can't think of a way to make it completely dynamic, without some element having a defined size.

Sorry for asking such a broad question but I haven't been able to narrow it down to anything more specific, so I'm wondering if anyone has a better idea for how to accomplish this. Essentially I just need an image with puzzle pieces over it that can be hidden to reveal the image.

Comment: I think I get what you are trying to complete.. Can you post a fiddle or codpen.. I think your problem is an easy fix.

Comment: not great with jsfiddle but i think i got most of it working [link](https://jsfiddle.net/vn0hmjom/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried for a while to fix what you had and ended up having to write javascript to handle the "square" board size. Once I did that, I ended up realizing that the whole thing was easier to write in javascript with absolute positioned DIVs for the 16 puzzle pieces and the 16 click regions. As a result I ended up with this:

```
<head>

<style>
#container{
  background-image: url('http://www.mpaquette.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/bck.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.piece {
  position:absolute;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
  </div>
</body>

<script>
var image_urls = [
"http://www.mpaquette.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/topLeft.png",
"http://www.mpaquette.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/topA.png",
"http://www.mpaquette.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/topB.png",
"http://www.mpaquette.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/topRight.png",
"http://www.mpaquette.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/leftA.png",
"http://www.mpaquette.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/midA.png",
"http://www.mpaquette.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/midB.png",
"http://www.mpaquette.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/rightA.png",
"http://www.mpaquette.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/leftB.png",
"http://www.mpaquette.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/midB.png",
"http://www.mpaquette.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/midA.png",
"http://www.mpaquette.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/rightB.png",
"http://www.mpaquette.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/btmLeft.png",
"http://www.mpaquette.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/btmA.png",
"http://www.mpaquette.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/btmB.png",
"http://www.mpaquette.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/btmRight.png" ];

function handleClick(element) {
  console.log(element.id);
  var image = document.getElementById("puzzle" + element.id);
  image.style.display = "none";

  // do any other click handling here
}

function build() {
  var div = document.getElementById("container");

  for(var i=0;i<16;i++) {

    var image = document.createElement("img");
    image.id = "puzzle" + i;
    image.className = "piece";
    image.src = image_urls[i];
    div.appendChild(image);

    var clickdiv = document.createElement("clickdiv");
    clickdiv.id = i;
    clickdiv.onclick = function() { handleClick(this); }
    clickdiv.className = "piece";
    div.appendChild(clickdiv);
  }
}

function resize() {
  var el = document.getElementById("container");
  var w = window.innerWidth;
  var h = window.innerHeight;
  var square;
  var size;

  console.log("("+w+","+h+")");
  if(w>h) size = h;
  else size = w;
  square = size + "px";

  el.style.minWidth = square;
  el.style.minHeight = square;
  el.style.maxWidth = square;
  el.style.maxHeight = square;

  var piece_size = (size/4) * 1.6;
  for(var i=0;i<4;i++) {
    var y = i*(size/4) + size/8;
    for(var j=0;j<4;j++) {
      var x = j*(size/4) + size/8;
      var clickdiv = document.getElementById((i*4+j));
      clickdiv.style.left = (x - size/8) + "px";
      clickdiv.style.top = (y - size/8) + "px";
      clickdiv.style.width = (size/4) + "px";
      clickdiv.style.height = (size/4) + "px";

      var image = document.getElementById("puzzle" + (i*4+j));
      image.style.left = (x - piece_size / 2) + "px";
      image.style.top = (y - piece_size / 2) + "px";
      image.style.width = piece_size + "px";
    }
  }
}
window.onresize = function(e) { resize(); }
window.onload = function(e) { build(); resize(); } 
</script>
</body>
```

Which you can try here:
https://jsfiddle.net/FrancisMacDougall/5v3cLh15/

Note that the jsfiddle only calls the resize() once - you would need to call it whenever the browser resizes as in the above code. edit:: just modified the jsfiddle to include continuous resizing....

Comment: Thank you so much! I figured using javascript might be easier, It's been so long since I've worked on web stuff I've just been flailing at attempting this, thanks again for your help!